# Align text to left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How to align text to left with a bullet using `itemize`?

Comment: You should really improve your question quality. Typically one should include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, wide = 0pt]
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{itemize}

Some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text.
\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide = 0pt]
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It includes a frame as well, a frame is not required. how to remove that

Comment: @user87834: That's only the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package, which is quite helpful to show the layout. Remove `showframe` and the frame on the page(s) will vanish.

Comment: Already done with that the format I am using shifts the text to the right Please let me know any changes in the following  \setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}   
\setlength{\textheight}{9.8in}  
\setlength{\headsep}{0.001cm}    
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}                so as to shift text to the left

Comment: For the frame, sory, I should have explained: it is the option `showframe` of geometry, that I used to prove the bullets are indeed at the left margin. Remove that option. For the shifting to the right, this comes probably the the geometry package loading, which seems to apply more sensible margins than the default. You have two solutions: either you remove the `geometry` package (I used it only for the ‘showframe’ option), or you define your layout directly with `geometry` (it's much easier than  the traditional way). However if you have a template, it might interfere.

Comment: @Bernard: What, if you load `enumitem` before `geometry`? I didn't try it...